# Removing phantom sockets in Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, client-server

I am making a game where a node server speaks to javascript clients using [socket.io](http://www.socket.io). Players can connect and disconnect from the game and the server keeps track of who is connected. However, I have found that on many occasions when i close the server, close all open client tabs, then restart a new node server, the number of clients connected seems incorrect.

For example, I will connect with just one client but the node debugger shows that the server is keeping track of three sockets.

This is a problem because often these orphaned clients will receive messages from the server or timeout, and this messes up the game logic on the server (it was not expecting this many players etc.)

I *think* the reason this is happening is:
 1. Clients in socket.io automatically attempt a reconnect periodically when they are disconnected
 2. When closing a tab the sockets associated with that page are not being "flushed" or cleared for some reason.
 3. When the server is closed and then started up again, these unflushed clients think "oh, the server is back up, i will try and reconnect"

How can I tell the difference between sockets that have had their tabs closed/were associated with the old server, and new clients attempting to connect to the newly restarted server? Or is there a way for me to ensure the clients get "flushed" when either the server is closed or a tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any code, I am really only guessing here.
http://socket.io/docs/#sending-and-receiving-events

Above, you will find code and I will copy it. Basically, you need to listen to the 'disconnect' event on the socket and remove your reference of the client from whatever array you are using to keep track of your clients.

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    // remove from list here
});
```

Connections from the browser will die on tab close and this event will be called when this happens. Yes, if you reopen the page, they will reconnect.

You should create some sort of "handshake" that actually adds a client to your list of game clients. Anyone can technically connect to a websocket. It can be as simple as emitting an "init" message that is empty but at least have something there.